# RegEx for computer name validation (cannot be more than 15 characters long, be entirely numeric, or contain the following characters...)

Tags: regex

I have these requirements to follow:

> Windows computer name cannot be more than 15 characters long, be
>   entirely numeric, or contain the following characters: ` ~ ! @ # $ % ^
>   & * ( ) = + _ [ ] { } \ | ; : . ' " , < > / ?.

I want to create a RegEx to validate a given computer name.

I can see that the only permitted character is `-` and so far I have this:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15}$/`

which matches almost all constraints except the "**not entirely numeric**" part.

How to add last constraints to my RegEx?

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression?

Comment: Doesn't that mean there may be any character but those specified above? It seems you need to use `/^(?!\d+$)[^\`~!@#$%^&*()=+_[\]{}\\|;:.'",<>\/?]{1,15}$/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/0W1JV7/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess the requirements for this are considered in terms of ASCII printable characters, so the only one that is not listed is hyphen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It'd better be for the sake of consistency in my own context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![0-9]{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15}$
```

Or simply use two regular expressions:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15}$
AND NOT
^[0-9]{1,15}$;
```

**Here is a live example:**

```js
var regex1 = /^(?![0-9]{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15}$/;
var regex2 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15}$/;
var regex3 = /^[0-9]{1,15}$/;

var text1 = "lklndlsdsvlk323";
var text2 = "4214124";

console.log(text1 + ":", !!text1.match(regex1));
console.log(text1 + ":", text1.match(regex2) && !text1.match(regex3));
console.log(text2 + ":", !!text2.match(regex1));
console.log(text2 + ":", text2.match(regex2) && !text2.match(regex3));
```

Comment: A negative lookahead is just what I needed. Thanks!